# VIM: Yank from one file and search in the other

Tags: search, vim

After I have opened a file include()ed with `gf`, how can I copy text from that file into the original file's search function?

For instance, if I am working on a PHP file and it has a line:

```
include("someFile.php");
```

I would put the cursor on `someFile.php` and press `gf`. In that file I see the text `function reallyLongFunctionName() {}`. I would like to search for that function in the original file. I can copy the function name with `v` and then `Ctrl-O` my way back to the original file, but now how do I perform the search?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just press `*` on the function name, and when you return to the original file it will already be highlighted. Press `n` to find the first instance.  `*` locates all instances of the word under the cursor in all buffers.

It sounds like you're doing a tag lookup (<kbd>Ctl</kbd>-<kbd>]</kbd>) in reverse.

Comment: Thank you! I cannot believe (though I know that I should) that it was this simple!

Answer (score 2):

I'd simply load the other file, navigate back (<kbd>C-o</kbd>) and start

`rea`<kbd>C-n</kbd>

to invoke buffer completion... (<kbd>C-n</kbd> and <kbd>C-p</kbd> work in pairs).

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure that I follow you. I am not familiar with Ctrl-X and the fine manual does not show it having any relevant function. Did you mean that I should copy the text in the 'other' file, then perform `/rea` (as in the beginning of the function name) in the original file?

Comment: -1. Quoting vim help (`:help ins-completion`): `keywords in the **current file** |i_CTRL-X_CTRL-N|`. You have to start search with `CTRL-N` only, no `CTRL-X` before it, and have the `'complete'` setting adapted.

Comment: @Benoit: ah. Memory error. Fixed. Funny how I type that all day, my fingers know the correct ways subconsciously :). By the way, the default complete option allows for this, I even run with `set complete-=i` usually

Comment: @sehe: now +1. Thanks for fixing :)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like exactly the problem [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) solves. Grab that, build a tags file, and then you just hit `Ctrl-]` over the function name (any tag name, actually) to search for that tag

Comment: ctags is great on my own servers, but I am often working on stock CentOS machines without root. Thanks, though.